# Prove the formula for max norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

Max norm can be defined as: $$\ ||A||_{1\infty} = \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$$

The hint i was given is that for certain *c* we have$\ ||Ax|| \le c||x||$ and so the following $\ ||A|| \le c$. To be honest i have no idea how to use this hint to prove above equality. I know that i can use the formula $$\ ||A||_{pq} = \max\frac{||Ax||_q}{||x||_p}$$Of course $\ x    \in  \mathbb{R}^n $ and $\ x \ne0$. However i don't know how to go further with this. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got your hint... as written, is very unclear, but what they wanted to says is that : If $c$ is s.t. $\|Ax\|_q\leq c\|x\|_p$ for all $x$, then $\|A\|_{pq}\leq c$.

Notice that $$\|A\|_{pq}=\max_{\|x\|_p=1}\|Ax\|_q=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|_q}{\|x\|_p}.$$

So, in your case, $(p,q)=(1,\infty )$, and the statement is equivalent than proving that if $\|Ax\|_\infty \leq \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$ for all $\|x\|_1=1$, then $\|A\|_{1\infty }\leq \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$. Which will implies by your hint, that $\|A\|_{1,\infty }\leq \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$ holds.

---

Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$ be s.t. $\|x\|_{1}=1$. Then, clearly
\begin{align*}
\|Ax\|_\infty &=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\{|a_{i1}x_1+...+a_{in}x_n|\}\\
&=|a_{j1}x_1+...+a_{jn}x_n|,\ \ \ \ \text{for some $j$}\\
&\leq \|x\|_1\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|a_{ji}|\\
&\leq \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|,
\end{align*}
as wished.

The fact that $\|A\|_{1,\infty }=\max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$ whenever $\|x\|_1=1$ is now straightforward and left as a Homework ;-).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but isn't the$\ ||Ax||_\infty \ge \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$ ?

Comment: Since you have the $=$, the obviously it's $\geq$. But you still have to prove it. @PiotrWj

Comment: But it's $\ ||Ax||_{1\infty}= \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$ and $\ ||Ax||_{\infty} = \sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|$

Comment: No, $$\|Ax\|_{1\infty } =\max_{1\leq {\color{red}i}\leq n}\leq \left|\sum_{j=1}^na_{{\color{red}i}j}x_j\right|.$$ 
And what you have to prove is that $\|A\|_{1\infty }=\max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$. We already proved that $\|A\|_{1\infty }\leq \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$, so it remains to prove the equality. Notice that $\|Ax\|_{1\infty }$ has no sense since $Ax$ is a vector whereas $\|\cdot \|_{1\infty }$ is a norm on the space of $n\times n$ real matrices.